# Tensorflow error in import tf.nn.rnn_cell

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am using Tensorflow 1.0.0 and Python 3.5. 
When I try to do:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)
```

I get the following error:

AttributeError

```
  <ipython-input-25-41a20d8458a7> in <module>()

      1 # Forward pass
      2 print(tf.__version__)
  --->3 cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)
      4 states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs_series, initial_state = init_state)
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.nn' has no attribute 'rnn_cell'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TensorFlow changes a lot of APIs before 1.0.

You'll need to replace `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell` by `tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell`

Answer (score 8):

I have same problem in **tensorflow 2.1** and when I used this code:

```
rnn_cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
            [lstm_cell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)],
            state_is_tuple = False,
        )
```

I faced with this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.nn' has no attribute 'rnn_cell'
```

Finally, I replaced `tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell` by `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell`, and then it worked well.
Please, replace `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)` by `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(state_size)`.

Comment: this worked for me, weirdly on some tf official page the import was just nn.rnn not nn.rnn_cell